# Loading wrong xib file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

Maybe I'm stupid but I spent the whole afternoon trying to figure out this one. I'm an Objective C novice, but have plenty experience in other languages.

I have two `NSCollectionView` - `*eventsView` and `*projectsView` inside a menu. Each with its own `itemPrototype` which are two subclasses of `NSCollectionViewItem` both with their own .xib files.

The problem is that it's always the first .xib file that loads - for both `NSCollectionViewItem`. So `projectsView` doesn't load its own .xib but it loads the `eventsView` one. The funny thing is if I delete that .xib, both load the second .xib which no one loaded before.

I've run out of keywords to search for on Google, so here I am.

The code (though I don't know it matters) is:

```
NSMenuItem *events = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
self.eventsView = [[NSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
HeadquartersEventsViewItem *eventsPrototype = [[HeadquartersEventsViewItem alloc] init];
[self.eventsView setItemPrototype:eventsPrototype];
[events setView:self.eventsView];
[self.menu addItem:events];

[self fetchEvents];

[self.menu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];

NSMenuItem *projects = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
self.projectsView = [[NSCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
HeadquartersProjectsViewItem *projectsPrototype = [[HeadquartersProjectsViewItem alloc] init];
[self.projectsView setItemPrototype:projectsPrototype];
[projects setView:self.projectsView];
[self.menu addItem:projects];

[self fetchProjects];
```

Where is the catch? Why does Xcode not differentiate between those 2 .xibs?

Comment: What is the file owner of every xib file?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya tried many times - same.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri the way it should be (I guess) - `HeadquartersEventsViewItem` in the HeadquartersEventsViewItem.xib and `HeadquartersProjectsViewItem` in the HeadquartersProjectsViewItem.xib

Comment: Maybe the binding are wrong and you bound both collection views to the same xib.Try to delete the other xib (the one that gets loaded), and see what happens.

Comment: These are XIB with windowControllers or only View with viewControllers? And how you are init & loading these xib's?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I already wrote in the original post. If i delete one, both load the other one :D

Comment: must be wrong bindings in interface builder.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya XIB with viewcontrollers. I created all of them via creating new NSCollectionViewItem subclass and checking the "With XIB for UI". The above is all the code I have regarding this. I thought Xcode loads all of that automagically.

Comment: @kitschmaster what bindings? I have views set on file owners and each file owner has the right class name.

Comment: What xibs are you talking about? I don't see anything in your posted code that explicitly loads a particular xib file. Shouldn't you be using initWithNibName:bundle: to initialize your collection view item?